# nodejs execute in order using foreach vs for

Tags: node.js, async-await

I wanna execute series of things in the same order for each item i have and collect the information then send statistics at the end.

here is the example code:

```
let listOfItems = [];
assignedItems.forEach(async (item) => {
    let id = item.myID;
    totalItemCount += await itemRepository.getItemCount(id);

    let itemDetail = await itemRepository.getDetails(id);
    listOfItems.push(item.name);
}, this);
console.log(listOfItems.length); // 0 ??
```

vs

```
let listOfItems = [];
for (let i = 0; i < assignedItems.length; i++) {
    let id = assignedItems[i].myID;
    totalItemCount += await itemRepository.getItemCount(id);

    let itemDetail = await itemRepository.getDetails(id);
    listOfItems.push(itemDetail.name);
}
console.log(listOfItems.length); // 5 as expected
```

output using foreach: 0 (because foreach is executed later)
output using for: 5 as expected (because for is executed as code execution is written)

Main issue is: foreach is executed after my console.logs which are written after foreach as i want to collect first all the details for the items and then send the data i have collected.

What the hell is doing on? how do i fix the issue using foreach?

Comment: I think your question is a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop/37576787

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.forEach()` won't work with `await` the way you want it to.  Just use an actual `for` loop with `await` if you want to serialize things.

If you have a problem with not using `.forEach()`, then please explain that problem so we can help solve that problem.

`.forEach()` is synchronous and will not `await` anything and there's no way to change it to do so.  You have to loop differently if you want each iteration of the loop to `await` your promise.  The `for` loop will do that for you in ES6 (that's an explicitly designed feature of ES6) or you can custom code your own manual loop that will `await`, but `.forEach()` won't do it.

> What the hell is doing on?

`.forEach()` is synchronous.  It doesn't `await` your promise.  That's how it is designed.

> how do i fix the issue using foreach?

You don't.   Use a regular `for` loop if you want to await each iteration of the loop before proceeding.  This is a feature of ES6 with regular `for` loops, not with `.forEach()`.

---

FYI, if you want a `.forEach()` like feature that will wait for a promise, you can use the [Bluebird promise library](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api-reference.html) and use something like `Promise.mapSeries()` or `Promise.each()`.  Those functions both look for a promise returned from their callback and don't execute the next iteration until those promises are resolved.  But, `array.forEach()` does not have that feature built in.

---

There are also design patterns using `.reduce()` and promises for sequencing through an array calling an async operations in series.  You can see examples of that pattern in these answers:

[how to write to new files sequentially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47721078/how-to-write-to-new-files-sequentially/47721202#47721202)

[Can Promise load multi urls in order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33886555/can-promise-load-multi-urls-in-order/33887054#33887054)

[iterating over promises node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46565970/iterating-over-promises-node-js/46570137#46570137)

[how to make synchronous http calls using promises in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36518624/how-to-make-synchronous-http-calls-using-promises-in-node-js/36525268#36525268)